# Deploying war into OSGI at Runtime

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, apache-karaf, equinox

My requirement is to deploy war files into OSGI at runtime.

For to achieve that I am trying through below codes:

```
BundleContext bundlecontext = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass()).getBundleContext();
Bundle b = bundlecontext.installBundle("file:" + "./war/testwar.war");
b.start();
```

But I am unable to achieve that, by using the above codes.

As I am new to OSGI I have very less idea of OSGi.
So I need help on this to achieve.

Comment: in Karaf, if you have `pax-war` feature installed, you'll have an _extender_ that can install your war and register as web application. There's a [sample](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/blob/pax-web-7.2.x/samples/war-introspection-bundle/pom.xml) project that shows that.

Answer (score 2):

OSGi runtime is not an application server but environment that manages modules (bundles). A `war` is not (usually) an OSGi bundle and can not be installed the way you do it.

There are many different ways to achieve what you want and it's hard to suggest something. Here are some of the them:

1. Convert the WAR to WAB (Web Application Bundle). This way you can install it into any OSGi runtime. You would also need to install other bundles that can handle web requests (HTTP Whiteboard implementation for example)
2. Use an OSGi based product that can automatically convert `war`s to `bundles`. [Liferay Portal](http://portal.liferay.dev/) does that but it may be too much to learn it if all you want is to run one app.
3. If you tagged the question with `apache-karaf` because that is your environment, then have a look at [War deployer](https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/#_war_deployer). That feature will allow you to install war files in Karaf. If you want to do it from code, you can have a look at the code of that feature and follow the same approach.

Comment: Thanks for your replay...
I tried to install by using `bundle:install -s webbundle:/war/testwar.war`
but I am getting error like `Error executing command: Error installing bundles:
        Unable to install bundle webbundle:/war/testwar.war: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to cache bundle: webbundle:/war/testwar.war`

Do you have any idea why I am getting this error.

Comment: If you are installing local file try `webbundle:file:///war/testwar.war` instead. Also make sure to provide `Bundle-SymbolicName` and `Web-ContextPath` headers on the URL. I don't know if those are mandatory (they may be autogenerated) but I'd play it safe and us them to know how to access the app later on.

Comment: Instead of passing war location in `bundlecontext.installBundle`, I tried to pass InputStream after doing some changes in manifest file as below
`File file = new File(WAR_FILE);
JarInputStream in = new JarInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(Files.newInputStream(file.toPath())));
Manifest manifest = in.getManifest();
Attributes m = manifest.getMainAttributes();
m.putValue("Webapp-Context", fName);
Bundle b = bc.installBundle(null,in);
b.start();`

but I am getting some error like org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error occurred installing a bundle. Can you plz help me on this?

Comment: I suggest to edit the question and add an update describing what have you done, why did you go that way and what is the new issue. This way you can provide more information (code, error messages, ...) which can be properly formatted and more readable.